# Calling grandchild's function in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am planning to use refs to call a function of a great-grandchild, but not able to figure out exactly how. Please help. Please don't mind syntactical mistakes. Heres the code:

Main.js

```
render(){
    <Board puzzle={puzzle} ref={ref => this.board = ref} solve={this.solve} editing={editing}
      onInit={this.onInit.bind(this)} onErrorMove={this.onErrorMove} onFinish={this.onFinish} erasing={this.state.erasing}/>
}
```

Board.js

```
render(){
    <Grid ref={ref => ref && (this.cells = ref.cells)} onPress={this.onCellPress} number={index} erasing={this.props.erasing}/>
}
```

Grid.js

```
render(){
  <Cell ref={ref => this.cells[index] = ref} key={'cell' + index} />
}
```

Cell.js; function to be called from Main.js

```
erase(){
 if(this.state.hints.length > 0){
   this.setState({
     hints: []
   })
 }
 else {
   this.setState({
     number: null
   })
 }
}
```

Comment: Change your architecture and don't call functions on grandchildren. Ideally, don't call functions even on children. Instead, move your `state` up the hierarchy.

Comment: Its too late to change the architecture, thats why looking the "ref" way to do it.

Comment: You'll spend more time trying to find work-arounds if you don't change your architecture.